# Can Hibernate update a single property?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate class with more than one property, I have heard that NHibernate tracks properties in files and only updates those properties that have changed. Is there similar functionality in Hibernate?

I have tried to get it to work using just a simple class load - then set one property - then flush changes. However this without fail updates all the properties in the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the dynamic-update property to true via annotation or in the class mapping which would exclude unmodified properties in the Hibernate’s SQL update statement. You can find a good reference [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/). By default, the dynamic-update is set to false so as to be backward compatible as it is somewhat new feature introduced.

Comment: it also negates lots of caching done by databases. So if you don't have huge attributes it doesn't scale as nice

Answer (score 0):

You can get Entity from db first then update ... try this example..

```
public final void updateEntity(EntityName entity){

  //get entity from db by id
  EntityName dbEntity = session.get(EntityName.class, item.getProductId());

   //set property
  dbEntity.setStatus(entity.getStatus());

  //and update
  session.update(dbEntity);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **@DynamicUpdate** annotation at the entity level, as shown [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-update-only-a-subset-of-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/).